# Powershell getting stuck when doing webrequest

Tags: powershell, webrequest

I currently have to get the size of some files stored on a webserver for the implementation of an update mechanism. Getting the file size works with my script, but whenever I call the function multiple times, it gets stuck at `WebRequest.GetResponse()`. When it gets stuck, I can't even stop the script with Ctrl-C. Does somebody know why this is happening or if there is a better way of doing this?

In the example I'm getting a test text file

Powershell script:

```
function GetWebFileSize($fileurl) {
    try {
        Write-host "Getting size of file $fileurl"
        $clnt = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($fileurl)
        $resp = $clnt.GetResponse()
        $size = $resp.ContentLength;
        Write-host "Size of file is $size"
        return $size
    }
    catch {  
        Write-host "Failed getting file size of $fileurl"
        return 0
    }
}


[int]$counter = 0;

while (1 -eq 1) {
    $counter++;
    GetWebFileSize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mxstbr/markdown-test-file/master/README.md"
    Write "Passed $counter"
}
```

[Output of powershell (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72JIk.png)
The output:

```
C:\> .\WebFileSizeTest.ps1
Getting size of file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mxstbr/markdown-test-file/master/README.md
Size of file is 1003
1003
Passed 1
Getting size of file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mxstbr/markdown-test-file/master/README.md
Size of file is 1003
1003
Passed 2
Getting size of file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mxstbr/markdown-test-file/master/README.md
Failed getting file size of https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mxstbr/markdown-test-file/master/README.md
0
Passed 3
Getting size of file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mxstbr/markdown-test-file/master/README.md
Failed getting file size of https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mxstbr/markdown-test-file/master/README.md
0
Passed 4
Getting size of file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mxstbr/markdown-test-file/master/README.md
Failed getting file size of https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mxstbr/markdown-test-file/master/README.md
0
Passed 5
Getting size of file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mxstbr/markdown-test-file/master/README.md
```

Comment: Some websites block HTML scrapers and other bots. You may need to change your agent string and/or keep some (random) delay between requests to hide the fact you are a bot.

Comment: I tested this aswell on the local server i'm getting the file from, and there is no bot detection / blocking. I'm getting the same result there, even if i change the user agent or I add a delay of a second

Comment: I suggest to remove the try-catch block, so you get to see the actual error message.

Comment: There's still no additional output

Comment: The equivalent in C# doesn't get stuck. The only difference is I'm closing the response after using, so that stream is disposed. Even with that change above code doesn't work. Have you tried using Poweshell command `Invoke-WebRequest` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @derloopkat for the solution. I forgot to Dispose the WebRequest object. So the code that's now working for me is:

```
    Write-host "Getting size of file $fileurl"
    $clnt = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($fileurl)
    $resp = $clnt.GetResponse()
    $size = $resp.ContentLength;
    $resp.Dispose();
    Write-host "Size of file is $size"
    return $size
```